# Adding a function to class member

Tags: c++, class

I'm not sure of the proper terminology here so I'm having trouble finding the answer to my question but here is what I want to achieve.

say I have

```
class ABC {
public:
    int number;
};
```

and I want to add a function inside int number's scope (I think is how you would say it). something like IsNeg() but I would like to use it like so:

```
ABC abc;
abc.number.IsNeg();
```

which would return true or false.  Would something like this be possible?

Comment: The term you are looking for is "extension method" (at least that's what it's called in C#). I do not know if C++ has that functionality, though a quick Google search gives a few hits that look promising.

Comment: If you make number a class or struct, then you could have `number.IsNeg()` and something like `number.value` to get the `int`.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour should be inside the class, so you do not need these nested `.` calls.

The following design delivers exactly what you want without adding special complexity of a custom class representing a value.

```
class ABC
{
public:
    int number;

    bool isNumberNegative() const
    {
        return number < 0;
    }
};

// ... //

ABC abc;
auto isNegative = abc.isNumberNegative();
```

This suggested solution is also in terms with the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no (take a look at [Extension methods in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5463009/3235496) and [C++ Extension functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7922112/3235496) for more details).

For operators that haven't been already defined by a class you can write overloads which work on that class and it's a *little* like method extensions.

However the "everything is an object paradigm" doesn't hold in C++ and free functions ([What's In a Class?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill02.htm)) / [Koenig lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) / namespaces are the C++ way.

---

In your example, you could:

- add a member function as in [David Packer's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/315052/149904) (`number` should probably be private)
- make `number` a class or `struct` ([Erik Eidt's comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/315050/adding-a-function-to-class-member#comment666271_315050))
- make `class ABC` a `struct` and work directly on the `number` data member
- write a free function

  ```
  bool is_neg(const ABC &abc)
  {
    return abc.number < 0;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Practically, this cannot be done with your piece of code. Because, C++ doesn't provide primitive types as class. Hence, `abc.number.IsNeg()` is not possible.

You can achieve it using the code given below. But I will not recommend this, instead follow @David's advice to avoid complexity.

```
class ABC {
public:
    Number number;
}
class Number {
public:
    int data;
    bool IsNeg() {
        return data < 0;
    }
}
```

Now you can write this:

```
ABC abc;
abc.number.IsNeg();
```